# como contar repeticiones consecutivas java

Tags: java

Necesito de su colaboración,estoy creando una matriz la cual tiene números 0 y 1, 
requiero un código el cual me cuente cuantos 0 solos o consecutivos están y me los almacene en algún lado. 
Esta es la matriz.

```
comparativo X 0[ 0 ]
comparativo X 1[ 0 ]
comparativo X 2[ 0 ]
comparativo X 3[ 1 ]
comparativo X 4[ 0 ]
comparativo X 5[ 0 ]
comparativo X 6[ 1 ]
comparativo X 7[ 1 ]
comparativo X 8[ 1 ]
comparativo X 9[ 0 ]
```

Me debe contar que en las posiciones 0,1,2 van 3 ceros. en la 4,5 van 2 ceros, en la 9 va 1 cero.

Tengo este codigo ya.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distancia1 {

    public static void main(String arg[ ]) {
         Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);  
        //Variables
        double arreglo [] = new double [99999999];
        int comparativo []= new int [99999999];
        int contador []= new int [99999999];
         int c=0,u=0,c1=0,m=0;  

          System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de numeros aleatorios");
          int ca = teclado.nextInt();//CA= Cantidad aleatorios
         System.out.println("Ingrese el intervalo menor");
           double ime = teclado.nextDouble();//IME Invervalo menor
            System.out.println("Ingrese el intervalo maximo");
            double ima = teclado.nextDouble();//IMA Invervalo maximo
          double pi = (double) (ima-ime);
        //Crear el arreglo con numeros aleatorios segun la cantidad de aleatorios ingresados  
        for (int i=0;i<ca;i++){
           arreglo [i] = (double) Math.random() ;               
           System.out.println("Arreglo X "+i+"[ "+arreglo[i]+" ]");               
            }   


           /* copia= java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(arreglo,1,ca);
          for (int i=0;i<copia.length;i++){  
              System.out.println("copia X "+i+"[ "+copia[i]+" ]");
                 }*/


         //realiza la comparacion de cada numero aleatorio si se encuentra en el rango de IME e IMA 
         for (int i=0;i<ca;i++){                  
             if (arreglo [i] >=ime && arreglo[i]<ima){
              comparativo [i]=1;
               System.out.println("comparativo X "+i+"[ "+comparativo[i]+" ]");
             }
             else{
                  comparativo [i]=0;
              System.out.println("comparativo X "+i+"[ "+comparativo[i]+" ]");
          }

           }  
          //Cuenta cuantos 0 y 1 hay.    
          for (int i=0;i<ca;i++){ 
              if (comparativo [i]==1)
                  u=u+1;
              }
                System.out.println("Cantidad de 1  " +u );
                for (int i=0;i<ca;i++){ 
              if (comparativo [i] ==0 )
                  c=c+1;                  
           }
           System.out.println("Cantidad de 0  "+c );

           //Cuenta con 0 hay consecutivos
          /* for (int i=0;i<ca;i++){ 
              if (comparativo [i]==1)
                contador [i]=0;  
              }
                for (int i=0;i<ca;i++){ 
              if (comparativo [i] ==0 )
                  contador [i]=1; 
              if (comparativo [i+1] ==0 )
                  contador [i]=1+; 
                    System.out.println("contador   "+i+"->"+contador [i] );
           }*/



         }
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿La matriz tiene que rellenarse aleatoriamente de ceros y unos? Por que leyendo el enunciado y mirando el código, creo que estas haciendo mas cosas de las que pides y ahí me pierdo

Answer (score -1):

```
int contadorConsecutivos = 0;
          for(int i = 1; i<comparativo.length;i++){
            if (comparativo[i] == 0){
                if (comparativo[i] == 0 && comparativo[i-1] == 0){
                    contadorConsecutivos++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Tu pregunta no se entiende bien. Segun lo que yo he entendido quieres contar cuantos 0 consecutivos hay en tu array. No se si eso sera lo que pides pero es lo que yo he entendido que pedias. Un problema que vas a tener que un array de entero pone como valor por defecto a 0, deberias dar otro valor al valor por defecto para que asi te funcionara el algoritmo.

Ademas generas un array inmenso cuando no lo necesitas tan grande. Con crear el array con el tamaño que te introduces por teclado tienes suficiente no crearlo a 999999.

Comment: Gracias. Voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: No me sirvio. Te voy a contar que debe hacer el programa. El usuario ingresa cuantos números aleatorios quiere generar (entre 0 y 1), luego ingresa un rango de valores para generar un comparativo, es decir, el ingresa 0,4 y 0,5. El programa valida si el primer numero del vector,esta en ese rango, si esta en ese rango creo un nuevo vector y le coloca un 1, si no esta le coloca un 0, así por la cantidad de números aleatorios que se generaron, ahora bien. luego de realizar esta validación, Me debe contar que en las posiciones 0,1,2 van 3 ceros. en la 4,5 van 2 ceros, en la 9 va 1 cero.y